# Asp.Net MVC Routing without controller and action X Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My application in ASP.NET MVC4 I have:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Logon/Autentica" timeout="120"></forms>
    </authentication>
```

routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Abcdef",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{conte}",
                defaults: new { controller = "CampanhaResposta", action = "Resposta" }
            );
```

Web.config:

```
  <location path="CampanhaResposta/Resposta">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

It don't works: `www.website.com/mycode` 
but it's working: `www.website.com/CampanhaResposta/Resposta/mycode`

Why?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Why are you using the `<location>` section to handle authorization in an ASP.NET MVC application instead of using the AuthorizeAttribute?

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"?

Comment: it's probably because /mycode is not the application root.

Answer (score 1):

You need change your routing to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Abcdef",
                url: "{action}/{conte}",
                defaults: new { controller = "CampanhaResposta", action = "Resposta", conte = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
```

It will return: `www.website.com/Resposta`

Answer (score 0):

When you're getting `www.website.com/mycode`, Routing thinks that "mycode" is a controller name. Even though you've provided default values for "controller" and "action" route parameters, they are not used because `url: "{controller}/{action}/{conte}"` expects "conte" the last. You will have to change the url template.

For example, if you change it to

`url: "{conte}/{controller}/{action}"`

and then get `www.website.com/mycode` again, "mycode" will correctly be treated as a value of the "conte" route variable. Also the default values for controller and action will kick in and you will get the result you are after.